# Change default font within all tikzpicture environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I want to have all tikz graphics in \sffamily font. However, I cannot set a base font for tikz, as it will be overridden, whenever I user, e.g., `font=\itshape`, for a node locally.

I tried to set a prefix such as `\tikzset{font/.prefix = {\sffamily}}`, as well as to change de default font using `\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}` and `\AtEndEnvironment`, respectively.
Also, I tried `\tikzset{execute at begin picture={\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}}`. However, nothing helped.

I'm simply looking for a proper way to set the base font in all tikz environments to `\sfdefault`.

In the following MWE, the first node should be sans, oblique, the other two nodes should be similar:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [font=\sffamily\itshape] {I should be in sans italic};
  \node [font=\itshape,below] {I should be in sans italic};
  \node [font=\bfseries,above] {I should be in sans oblique};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzset{nodes={font=\sffamily}}`

Comment: @Symbol1 That won't work. If you subsequently say `\node [font=\itshape]` you'll get italic serif. The OP wants the result to be italic sans (probably substituted as oblique sans, but that's a different matter).

Comment: `execute at picture begin` returns an error, so I don't know where that is from or how you defined it.

Comment: @cfr There is still a chance: `node font`. Otherwise one can do `\tikzset{add font/.code={\preto\tikz@textfont{#1}}}`.

Comment: @Symbol1 I didn't even know there was a `node font`. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a simple solution (if you don't already use `every picture` style). Add the following line in your preamble:

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [font=\sffamily\itshape] {I should be in sans italic or sans oblique};
  \node [font=\itshape,below] {I should be in sans italic or sans oblique};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `/utils/exec`? Thank you.

Comment: @codeaviator `/utils/exec` is a key that simply executes the given code (see p.893, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a).

Answer (score 3):

This changes the definition of the Ti*k*Z `font` option and adds an additional `base font` option. It is (almost) completely untested. It is probably extremely fragile. It may cause your cat to do as you say or otherwise destroy the world as you know it.

## *Caveat emptor*

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{base font}{\def\tikz@base@textfont{#1}}
\tikzoption{font}{\def\tikz@textfont{\tikz@base@textfont#1}}
\tikzset{
  base font=\sffamily,
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [font=\sffamily\itshape] {I should be in sans italic or sans oblique};
  \node [font=\itshape, below] {I should be in sans italic or sans oblique};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: all sans]