# Tikz - Set all nodes in sans serif font

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

So far I had the understanding that providing font commands after a "parental" scope/more global definition was given, is *additional*, but I was wrong.

How can I get nodes which are *only* set in the sans serif font?

## Picture of MWE

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
DIV=12,
paper=a4,
]{standalone}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{zlmtt}
\usepackage[scale=0.8558]{tgheros}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\sffamily,
every node/.style={
    font=\sffamily,
},]
\node at (0,0) {123 - in sans!};
\node[font=\bfseries] at (0,-1cm) {123 not sans :(} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your setting, `font=\bfseries` overrides `font=\sffamily`. However, if you use `node font` instead of font in order to apply either of them, it works. This is because Ti*k*Z will apply both `font` and `node font`.

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
DIV=12,
paper=a4,
]{standalone}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{zlmtt}
\usepackage[scale=0.8558]{tgheros}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node at (0,0) {123 - in sans!};
\node[node font=\bfseries] at (0,-1cm) {123 now sans ;-)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In principle, you may reverse the roles of `font` and `node font`. However, the pgfmanual says on p. 223

[image]

whereas for `node font` (see p. 222) this restriction seems not to apply:

[image]

Therefore, I'd like to argue one should use those modifiers like `\bfseries`, which change the dimensions of the text (more) with `node font` rather than just `font`.

Comment: Thank you! And based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359570/change-default-font-within-all-tikzpicture-environments, apparently there is also the option `/utils/exec={\sffamily},`. I just found that, btw.

Comment: @henry Thanks! I did not know that.

Comment: I didn't know `node font`, +1!